# What makes 'locate' so fast compared with 'find'?

Tags: linux, locate

In my mind, both [`locate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) and [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) finds a file, but why does `locate` run so fast?

According to its documentation, `locate`:

> DESCRIPTION 
> locate reads one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes file names matching at >least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line.

What files are in that database, and is every created file in that database?

Comment: Ultimately, spatial locality of the list of file names on disk.  `locate` reads them from one contiguous file (which might have some compression like common-prefix removal), while `find` has to read them from the filesystem where each directory has its list of filenames in a different sector.  Disk random access is slow, and having to make some open and getdents system calls for each directory isn't great either.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> In my mind, both locate and find finds a file, but why does locate run so fast?

`find` searches the file system itself. It is optimised for telling you everything (including the content of files that can be many gigabytes in size) a given file for a specific path and for being written to frequently.

`locate` searches a database generated from previously indexing the file system. The database is optimised for the types of searches `locate` performs.

> What files are in that database, and is every created file in that database?

The database is populated by [`updatedb`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/updatedb.htm). The files in it are determined by what options are passed to `updatedb`. Files will be in it unless they are outside the areas being searched or if they have been created since `updatedb` last ran.

For example, my default install of Ubuntu has:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS afs autofs binfmt_misc ceph cgroup cgroup2 cifs coda configfs curlftpfs debugfs devfs devpts devtmpfs ecryptfs ftpfs fuse.ceph fuse.cryfs fuse.encfs fuse.glusterfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse fuse.mfs fuse.rozofs fuse.sshfs fusectl fusesmb hugetlbfs iso9660 lustre lustre_lite mfs mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 ocfs ocfs2 proc pstore rpc_pipefs securityfs shfs smbfs sysfs tmpfs tracefs udev udf usbfs"
```

In the `/etc/updatedb.conf` file.

So it indexes everything except for certain directories which shouldn't be indexes for various (but hopefully fairly obvious) reasons and a bunch of different file system types (typically ones containing secret data, data on remote file systems, and system APIs).

Comment: locate also has some delay in reflecting additions, deletions, or changes to the filesystem; the updatedb has to run before the change is seen.

Comment: @mpez0 — Yes, that is why I said "or if they have been created since updatedb last ran" in this answer

Comment: Also worth noting that I have encountered systems where `locate` is installed, but `updatedb` is not enabled.  Therefore, it is quite possible for `locate` to return no results at all or - worse, as it's harder to dianose - very old results from the one time when `updatedb` was actually run.